# GITHUB: error 403 -> Can't git push even when using PAT (token)

Tags: git-push

I deleted my account to remake a brand new one with the same email address. I started creating my PAT token as well and I am having an issue with git push. I have tried looking everywhere on the web but no answers. I get this error:

"remote: Permission to <my.username>/test.git denied to <my.username>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<my.username>/.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

I've tried several new repositories thinking that the the link was corrupted? But still the same. Even tried entering different usernames.
Here is a step by step of what I go through:

1. git push
2. Username for 'https://github.com': || (cursor) So I entered <my.username>
3. Password for 'https://<my.username>@github.com': <my.PAT.token>

OUTPUT:
remote: Permission to <my.username>/.git denied to <my.username>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<my.username>/".git"/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Am I doing something wrong?
I even tried putting my password.

Thank you in advance! Looking forward to your response!

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong? I even tried putting my password.

The password would not work (not since [Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/))

Regarding the token, I would recommend, at least for testing:

- a [classic token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic) (instead of a fine-grained)
- with a [scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes) set to `repo`.

An incorrect scope could explain your error message.

---

The [OP kquetat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19975125/kquetat) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391941/github-error-403-cant-git-push-even-when-using-pat-token/75392225#comment133036855_75392225) the scope issue:

> I think my issue there was that I thought I added on my checklist the repo part, but apparently I didn't.

Comment: Problem SOLVED. I think my issue there was that I thought I added on my checklist the repo part, but apparently I didn't... Thank you!

Comment: @kquetat- Great, well done! I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.